# Select data from previous result of data

Tags: python, mysql

Sorry. I am new to expressing SQL statement in Python.

I am trying to do "Select x .. " from previous result of query.

For example, I have a first query (sql1):

```
sql1 = 'select course_id, record_id from Courses ' \
       ' where ( record_id not in ("TEST", "TEST123")) '
cursor.execute(sql1)
e = cursor.fetachall()
```

When I tried to do it without breaking down queries, I got an error due to different data type.

Now, how do I go about selecting from sql1 (this time I have to add one calculation of data) ?

```
sql2 = ' select course_id, max(record_id) + 1 from ... ? '
```

Comment: `select course_id, max(record_id) + 1 from (select course_id ... from ...where ) as some_table_alias_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sql1 a subquery of sql2.  For example:

```
 """select course_id, max(record_id) + 1 from 
   (select course_id, record_id from Courses
    where  record_id not in ('TEST', 'TEST123'))"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a view to store the query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS
select course_id, record_id from Courses 
where ( record_id not in ("TEST", "TEST123"));

select course_id, max(record_id) + 1 from v;
```

With this you will need only one query with Python.

```
sql1 = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v AS
select course_id, record_id from Courses 
where ( record_id not in ("TEST", "TEST123"));

select course_id, max(record_id) + 1 from v;'
cursor.execute(sql1)
e = cursor.fetachall()
```

More information about view: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: Is this Python ? It looks like script from Microsoft View

Comment: @KingJava It's mysql